# Can anyone help me display this php code in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I have sat 3 days trying to figure out Smarty, but I don't feel very much smartyer :)
Here is my php code:

**somefile.php**

```
include('libs/Smarty.class.php');
require( "configs/config.php" );
// create object

$smarty = new Smarty;     
function homepage($params, $smarty, $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$list = array();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
$article = new Article( $row );
$list[] = $article;
}

// Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
$totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
$conn = null;
return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );


if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
if ( isset( $data['publicationDate'] ) ) $this->publicationDate = (int) $data['publicationDate'];
if ( isset( $data['title'] ) ) $this->title = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['title'] );
if ( isset( $data['summary'] ) ) $this->summary = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['summary'] );
if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];

$results = array();
$results['articles'] = $data['articles'];
$results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];

$smarty->assign("articles", $data['articles']);
$smarty->assign("totalRows", $data['totalRows']);
$smarty->assign("id", $data['id']);
$smarty->assign("publicationDate", $data['publicationDate']);
$smarty->assign("title", 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk');
$smarty->assign("summary", 'lllllllllllllllllllllll');
$smarty->assign("content", 'øøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøøø');
}


// display it
$smarty->display('index2.tpl');
```

**index2.tpl**

```
    {include file="header.tpl"}
{debug}
      <h1>Article Archive</h1>
{assign var=results value={cycle values="totalRows,articles,title,publicationDate,id"}}

      <ul id="headlines" class="archive">


{foreach $articles['articles'] as $article}
        <li>
          <h2>
            <span class="pubDate">{$publicationDate}</span><a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId={$id}">{$title}</a>
          </h2>
          <p class="summary">{$summary}</p>
        </li>

{/foreach}

      </ul>

            <p><a href="./archive.php">Articles Archive</a></p>
        {include file="footer.tpl"}
```

The errors I get are:

```
Notice: Undefined index: articles in /var/www/www.mypage.com/htdocs/smarty/templates_c/cd9ff0835daf703adc0ed3991c1d26021d9fcc09.file.index2.tpl.php on line 42

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/www.mypage.com/htdocs/smarty/templates_c/cd9ff0835daf703adc0ed3991c1d26021d9fcc09.file.index2.tpl.php on line 42
```

Comment: `$data['articles']` does not exist in your code, but you use it. You have id, publicationDate, title, summary and content. Nothing else.

Comment: I have the:    $results['articles'] = $data['articles']; in the result array, it comes from the "while" command in the sql code. I'm totally new to both php and smarty, so hope you bare with me. :)

Comment: I also tried changing articles to article, and data to results, but still the same errors

Comment: If you want to receive more useful comments and possibly some good answers then I suggest updating your question with the contents of the `index2.tpl` file because the issue rests on line 42 of that file and you are not showing us the file. If you tell your doctor that your toe hurts but you don't want to take off your shoe to show him/her your toe then you can only expect sarcasm, speculation, and unwillingness to be useful from the doctor, correct?

Comment: The inde2.tpl is at the bottom of my original post, but the error for some reason points to a template in templates_c and in "/htdocs/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php" if I delete the once in templates_c.

Comment: Line 41-44 in the templates_c variant looks like this if that helps. 

 `code` (  <?php  $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['article'] = new Smarty_Variable; $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['article']->_loop = false;
     $_from = $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['articles']->value['articles']; if (!is_array($_from) && !is_object($_from)) { settype($_from, 'array');}
    foreach ($_from as $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['article']->key => $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['article']->value) {
    $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['article']->_loop = true;)

Comment: I edited your answer. Is it accurate? Also I had no clue you commented on this but I rather checked back out of curiosity. A useful tip for StackOverflow is to use the `@` symbol followed by a username and this will alert that person of your comment. So to get my attention you would throw `@MonkeyZeus` anywhere in your comment.

Comment: I have no professional experience with SMARTY in specific but it is a templating language so I am pretty sure it stores a copy of `index2.php` prepended with a relevant ID for easy retrieval later. It should essentially be your `index2.php` but simply "cached" for faster access. It stems from `index2.php`

Comment: What smarty version are you using? Also, does a var_dump of $results['articles'] (in somefile.php) returns something?

Comment: @Borgtex I am using 3.1.15. Dont know if I do the var dump thing right (Iused {$articles|print_r}), but nothing is printed in the template. The debug shows this: `$SCRIPT_NAME  Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "/smarty/index3.php"
->nocache = false
->scope = "file:index2.tpl"
$smarty  Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = null
->nocache = false
->scope = "file:index2.tpl"`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for your tips and editing. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that, for some reason, you assume that when you do

```
$smarty->assign("articles", $data['articles']);
```

they key 'articles' is included, wich is not, only the contents of it. So there is no such $articles['articles'] passed to the template, in he same way there is no $id['id'], only $id. Try to do the foreach with just $articles:

```
{foreach $articles as $article}
```

Comment: Yes, I also think that is the problem. The code looked like this in the original working php file:    `<?php foreach ( $results['articles'] as $article ) { ?>` The SQL, WHILE, IF ISSET and RESULTS ARRAY -snippets in my original post here is also from working phpcode.